# convert from char* to char[] in c

Tags: c

I wrote this code:

```
char *del;
char *str1;
int d = 0, i = 0, s = 0;
//char str[] = new char[29];
printf("enter the nember of delim elements: ");
scanf("%d", &d);
prinf("\nenter number of str elements: ");
scanf("%d", &s);

/* Initial memory allocation */
del = (char *) malloc(d * sizeof(char));
str1 = (char *) malloc(s * sizeof(char));
for(i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    scanf("%s", del+i);
}
```

and now I would like to know how can I copy `*del` to `del []`?

because after that I need to send `del []` to a function

thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `del []`= `*del`

Comment: Change `del = (char *) malloc(d * sizeof(char));` to `del = malloc(d * sizeof(char*));` because it is an array of string pointers. Then in your loop, allocate the memory for each input with `del[i] = malloc(s+1)`. The `+1` is for the string terminator. Delete `str1` and its gubbins.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to do any copying.  This:

```
void func(char d[]) { ... }
```

Is the same as this:

```
void func(char *d) { ... }
```

An array does not get copied in its entirety when it is passed to a function.  What actually happens is that a pointer to the first element in the array is passed.

So if you have this:

```
char *d;
```

Or this:

```
char d[100];
```

Both can be passed to a function with either of the two definitions above.